# Using Mailkit : "The SMTP server has unexpectedly disconnected."

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient, mailkit, smtp-auth

I am trying to use a free SMTP relay from SendGrid to send emails from my ASP.NET application. I can connect to the server, but when I try to authenticate, I get this error : "The SMTP server has unexpectedly disconnected."

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                (sender, certificate, certChainType, errors) => true;
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

            // connection
            client.Connect("smtp.host", 465, true);
            client.Authenticate("UserName", "Password");//error occurs here

            client.Send(email);
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
```

Once again, I can connect without any problem, but when I try to authenticate, I get the previously mentionned error...

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v2-csharp-code-example/

Comment: That's not quite what I need since I'm using Mailkit. I'm starting to think that maybe SendGrid isn't the most appropriate service for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue changing from SendGrid to gooogle's free SMTP service for all of their users. Simply follow the steps [here](https://www.siteground.com/kb/google_free_smtp_server/)
and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 9):

You have to supply:

- **Username**: is `apikey` (as a hard-coded value 'apikey').
- **Password**: is the apikey you generated from the web, which is a big hashy-like string.

You can find this on their [docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/integrating_with_the_smtp_api.html). But it was hard to find.

Comment: And unlike the Telnet example on their site you *don't* need to Base64 encode either username or API key.